# OpenVPN using google authenticator

Tags: authentication, openvpn, freeradius

I'm a little new to OpenVPN. I'm trying to get google authenticator to work with OpenVPN but I'm having a little trouble. Currently I'm tring to setup a radius server to run the authentication then have the radius server use google authenticator as part of the authentication process. I feel like there has to be a better way to do this. If anyone has done this before or knows a better way to go about it some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to use Google authenticator with OpenVPN that is to say add a factor to your OpenVPN account or you're setting up a radius server where you want to add a factor of authentication?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Its a reasonable Q. OP just wants to know how to add 2FA to OpenVPN using Google Authenticator. Indeed, radius is not needed but this is just part of the Q and is not being presented as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extention made for OpenVPN for OTP (One Time Password).
This extention includes Google Authenticator software tokens.

https://github.com/evgeny-gridasov/openvpn-otp